# Problema al enviar pdf desde con google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Mi script obtiene los datos de una línea de google spreadsheet.
Crea un documento de google desde un molde.
Reemplaza los datos de la línea  por las "etiquetas" dentro del documento.
Y envía el documento en pdf a un email.

El problema es que los datos no reemplazan las etiquetas hasta después de la ejecución del script.
Con lo cual lo que se envía es una copia del molde (envía el nuevo documento, no el molde). Pero sin reemplazar los datos, y cuando el script termina la ejecución, reemplaza todos los datos.

```
> function envioCertificado4() 
  

    var datosRegistros = hojaRegistro.getRange(2, 1, hojaRegistro.getLastRow(), hojaRegistro.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  //FOR PARA CHEQUEAR ESTADO
  for (var i = 0; i < hojaRegistro.getLastRow() - 1; i++) {
    var filaDeInfo = datosRegistros[i];
    var Marcatemporal = filaDeInfo[0]
    var Constructorobra_Constructor = filaDeInfo[7]
    var Expediente = filaDeInfo[11]
    var Fecha = filaDeInfo[15]
    var Firma = filaDeInfo[16]
    var Estado = filaDeInfo[17]

    if (Estado == "" && Marcatemporal != "") {
      var valorFila = i + 2

      ///CREA HOJA DOC DESDE MOLDE
      var nuevoCertificado = moldeCertificado.makeCopy("Certificado " + Constructorobra_Constructor + " " + fecha, DriveApp.getFolderById(idCarpetaCertificados));

      ///INCRUSTAR LOS DATOS
      var Certificado = DocumentApp.openByUrl(Url_nuevoCertificado);
      var body = Certificado.getBody();
      body.replaceText("<<Marcatemporal>>", Marcatemporal);
      body.replaceText("<<Expediente>>", Expediente);
      body.replaceText("<<Fecha>>", Fecha);
      body.replaceText("<<Firma>>", Firma);

      //ENVIAR EMAIL CON PDF ADJUNTO
      var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(Id_nuevoCertificado)
      MailApp.sendEmail("hola@hola.com", "prueba", 'Envío el Archivo adjunto', {
        attachments: [pdf.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías mostrar más código, para ver el orden en que ocurre cada cosa.

Comment: El código está incompleto, por ejemplo, no se incluye la declaración de `hojaRegistro`, `Id_nuevoCertificado` y posiblemente otras variables. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar un [mcve] (esto debe incluir una breve descripción de la fuente de datos y datos de ejemplo).